# Error during install of gfortran lapack for JAGS

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, lapack, jags

I am new to Linux and unfamiliar with gfortran.

I am trying to install gfortran lapack (according to instructions [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GfortranBuild#LAPACK_.28Linear_Algebra_PACKage.29)) to install JAGS for R on a Linux Mint 17.2 64 bit machine. My system settings are:

```
[14:20] ~/lapack-3.6.1$ uname -a
Linux X1Carbon 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On running `make` in the lapack directory, this is the error received:

```
[14:10] ~/lapack-3.6.1$ make
( cd INSTALL; make; ./testlsame; ./testslamch; ./testdlamch; \
    ./testsecond; ./testdsecnd; ./testieee; ./testversion )
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/joanna/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL'
gfortran -O2 -mtune=pentium4 -c lsame.f -o lsame.o
f951: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
make[1]: *** [lsame.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/joanna/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL'
/bin/sh: 1: ./testlsame: not found
/bin/sh: 1: ./testslamch: not found
/bin/sh: 1: ./testdlamch: not found
/bin/sh: 2: ./testsecond: not found
/bin/sh: 2: ./testdsecnd: not found
/bin/sh: 2: ./testieee: not found
/bin/sh: 2: ./testversion: not found
make: *** [lapack_install] Error 127
```

Other sites such as [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54097) reference a similar error but it is to do with a `-march=i686` flag which is not present in the gfortran command line that is run.

Could anyone suggest what the problem is and how to fix it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `make.inc` from instruction, instead use `make.inc.example` provided with source code (just copy `make.inc.example` to `make.inc`).

Comment: Excellent, the gfortran command ran fine. Many thanks.